# Should Stack Overflow really suggest that authors request clarification about their own question?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts, automatic-comments

Once upon a time I answered a question I had posted. I received an automatic looking answer/suggestion.

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post

Is this best practice? It looks kind of silly to me. Shouldn't you just say

> This does not provide an answer to the question.

I'm never going to request clarification from myself about my own response.

Comment: It's not about clarification of your own answer, but from the OP. And it's automated, so it doesn't distinguish if you had answered yourself.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But they are both the author of the answer and the question.

Comment: This is an edge case, I suspect it doesn't happen often that a self-answer is flagged as 'not an answer'.

Comment: We have default comments to pick from and in the review queue we get presented the answer (and with a bit effort we can see the question). Those stock comments match 99% of the cases. That we slip on self-answers is unfortunate but not something that has high prio to be changed or fixed.

Comment: I'm sure it is an edge case, but I find that just because something doesn't happen very often, doesn't mean that we should pretend that it never happens. Why is it hard to add a new default response?

Comment: @SlightlyKosumi: You didn't provide a link to your answer, so it is hard to tell, which choice is appropriate. The reviewer could choose *This answer should be an edit to the question
Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.*

Comment: @dur My question is absolutely not about 1 specific post and answer, it is about the general issue of is this an appropriate response to pick for an author who answers his own question (badly). I've already gotten 9 down votes for asking it, but I don't really see why. Still don't think an author should be told to request clarification from themselves as best practice, although of course I am accepting it is minor issue.

Comment: @SlightlyKosumi: Maybe the reviewer chose the wrong reason? There are other reasons, one of them I wrote in my comment. The reviewer could also choose no comment at all. A mistake! Where is the problem?

Comment: @dur Yes, I can see that other answers can be chosen. Personally I think it is a mistake to ask an author to request clarification from themselves, but that hasn't wrecked my life as I have some sense of perspective about these things. My question is just making an indirect suggestion - isn't this a silly autoresponse to allow reviewers to make.

Answer (score 9):

What you got is an automatic review comment from the "Low Quality Posts" queue.

What that means is that someone reviewed your (self) answer as "Recommend Deletion" with the reasoning "This is commentary on another post".

It's an edge case that self-answers get reviewed as "should be a comment instead", since OPs can always comment on their own posts and those kinds of NAA are usually given by people who lack the reputation to comment but abuse the answer feature instead to provide their comments.

An automated mechanism to remove part of the auto-comment that adresses non-OPs is probably of dubious value and not worth developer time spent.

Comment: Okay, but why is it hard to add an additional option in the queue? It doesn't sound like best practice to give low quality auto-responses to low-quality posts.

Comment: @SlightlyKosumi Because a) a dev has to make that option and b) reviewers have to realize its a self-answer when reviewing, which isn't obvious in the UI.

Comment: Normally it is not hard for a developer to develop. :) I am not sure if it is best practice that in the review queue you cannot see if an answer is a self answer, probably I would need a lot more knowledge of the internal workings of the system to decide on that. Anyway, I can understand what happened now.